# onStartTemporaryDetach() in View

Tags: android, android-view, textureview

The android docs says

> This is called when a container is going to temporarily detach a
>   child, with ViewGroup.detachViewFromParent.

Now what is this "temporary detach" and "permanent detach". When exactly is this method called?

I am using `TextureView` and i found that this method gets called before `onSurfaceTextureDestroyed` on the `TextureView` when i open a new `Activity`(Activity 2) from the `TextureView's` screen(Activity 1) but it doesnt get called when i close the `Activity 1` using the back button.